# Type of an attribute in an xml file with lxml

Tags: python, types, attributes, xsd, lxml

im using python and lxml to read xml files, which are validated against an xsd file. I want to find out the xs:type of an attribute.

My code until now:
The XSD

```
...      
<xs:complexType name="io" >
  <xs:attribute name="number" type="xs:decimal" use="optional" default="5.9"/>
</xs:complexType>
...
```

The XML

```
...
<io number="1.1">
...
```

Then Python code:

```
with open(self.xmlSchemaFilename) as schema:
     xmlschema_doc = objectify.parse(schema)
self.xmlschema = etree.XMLSchema(xmlschema_doc)
parser = etree.XMLParser(schema = self.xmlschema,
               attribute_defaults = True, remove_blank_text=True)
with open(self.xmlFilename) as myfile:
    tree = objectify.parse(myfile, parser)  
    #this correctly asserts the type from the xsd
root = tree.getroot()
self.xmlRoot = objectify.fromstring(etree.tostring(root))
self.xmlschema.assertValid(self.xmlRoot)
```

Now i can access the type of all child nodes via

```
type(self.xmlRoot.child)
```

and it returns the correct type from the xsd and gets something like

```
<type 'lxml.objectify.IntElement'>
```

but for attributes, which i access via

```
self.xmlRoot.child.attrib['number']
```

the type is always str regardless the xsd specification. How an i get the type for attributs?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible. I wouldn't mind being proven wrong, but it is hard to see how information about the type of an attribute could be provided by lxml.

The [`lxml.objectify`](http://lxml.de/objectify.html) API has "typed" Element classes (such as `IntElement`), but there are no classes representing attributes. In lxml (and ElementTree; upon which lxml is based), attributes are properties of Elements, and when you ask for attribute values you get strings.